# Delete a row in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with a delete icon as one column and update icon as another column. On click of update, the first cell is set on focus.

On click on delete I want to delete that selected row, but I get the error "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead." with the following code:

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid Name="grdList" Margin="3,16,0,5" RowHeight="30" ColumnWidth="*"
          ItemsSource="{Binding  List,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="434" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFB9BBFF">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="0" Header="Property"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=Property}"/>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Update"  MinWidth="50" MaxWidth="50">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                                 Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="Icons/Update.jpg"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete"  MinWidth="50" MaxWidth="50">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                                 Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="Icons/Delete.jpg"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**C#:**

```
private void EventSetter_OnHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    object source = e.OriginalSource;
    if (source.GetType() == typeof(Image))
    {
        grdList.IsReadOnly = false;

        selectedRow = FindParent<DataGridRow>(sender as DependencyObject);

        if (((DataGridCell)sender).Column.Header.ToString().ToUpperInvariant() == "DELETE")
        {
            grdList.Items.Remove(selectedRow);
        }
        else
        {
            DataGridCellsPanel panel = FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPanel>(selectedRow);

            DataGridCell dgc = panel.Children[0] as DataGridCell; 
            dgc.Focus();
            grdList.BeginEdit();

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Also How to add the delete function with the "Delete" key together with the click on the delete cell.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect on **`Delete`** i.e. in `EventSetter_OnHandler`, you must be removing items from the **`Items`** collection of dataGrid. Something like this:

```
grdList.Items.Remove(someItem);
```

But as the error is self explanatory

> "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify
>   elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."

You have binded ItemsSource to some collection, so you need to remove item from it. You **can't modify the Items collection directly when binding ItemsSource with some collection**. It should be something like:

```
List.Remove(someItem);
```

Comment: Thanks.. Is it possible to initiate the default delete option in WPF datagrid on the click?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the SelectedItem of your `DataGrid` to a property. Then you can call

```
List.Remove(SelectedDataGridItem);
```

SelectedDataGridItem is the property which the Selected Item is bound to

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
grdList.Items.RemoveAt(grdList.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: Though probably a fine answer, try to avoid code-only responses.  Consider adding an explanation

Comment: Has the same problems as 'Remove'. Not allowed if 'ItemsSource' is bound to a collection.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem, i solved it so:

```
yourrowbindingobject row = (yourrowbindingobject)yourdatagrid.SelectedItems[0];

ObservableCollection<yourrowbindingobject> data = (ObservableCollection<yourrowbindingobject>)yourdatagrid.ItemsSource;
data.Remove(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to remove a datagrid row using button click, I solved it as below:

Datagrid rows populated by data retrieved from SQL database:

```
/* Assign ItemsSource of DataGrid. */
dataGridSupplier.ItemsSource = Ldtbl.DefaultView;

 DataRowView dr = dataGridSupplier.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
 DataRow dr1 = dr.Row;

/* Remove selected item from the datagrid after successfully updating database. */
Ldtbl.Rows.Remove(dr1);
```