# How to delete rows from DataGrid when SelectionUnit="Cell" in the GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that has SelecitonUnit set to "Cell" and I really cannot figure out how to delete a whole row. Normally I would just select row and press delete button(like I do in my other datagrid with default SelectionUnit) but it doesn't work like that. I tried implementing my own delete functionality but there has to be a better solution.

The DataGrid

```
<DataGrid Name="XdataBom" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" Height="1080" Width="1920" VerticalAlignment="Top" KeyDown="XdataBom_OnKeyDown">
           <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Montować" Binding="{Binding Montowac, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ilość" Binding="{Binding Ilosc, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Desygnator" Binding="{Binding Desygnator, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Typ montażu" Binding="{Binding Typ, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Obudowa" Binding="{Binding Obudowa, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wartość" Binding="{Binding Wartosc, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
       </DataGrid>
```

There's a KeyDown event that handles pasting into the grid but I didn't override the delete key in any way.

Comment: You can change SelectionUnit to FullRow and SelectedItems will return the collection of selected rows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcells?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: But i need SelectionUnit to be Cell not Row. I have to be able to select multiple cells(it won't always be a full row). But if someone will select whole row of cells and press delete button it needs to be deleted.

Comment: There are some questions in SO about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517849/delete-a-row-in-wpf-datagrid) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761405/delete-datagrid-row-wpf)

Comment: Okay so I need a separate functionality for this. Thank You